# How to play a video from gallery with providing the file url

Tags: codenameone

in my database , i have in my entity the attribute "path" which contains videos path and i want to load the videos from my gallery when i consult each object , i've been trying to mess with [MediaPlayer](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/components/MediaPlayer.html)
but it got me to nothing 
i also tried this code but it got me nowhere nothing is displaying

```
final Form hi = new Form("MediaPlayer", new BorderLayout());
  final MediaPlayer mpPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    try{

          url = "file:///C:/Users/TR3x/Downloads/720P_1500K_202660741.mp4.mp4";
         InputStream is = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(url);
         String strMime = "video/mp4";
                System.out.println("Input Stream" + is.available());
                mpPlayer.setName("bla");
                mpPlayer.setDataSource(is, strMime, new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("reset the clip for playback");
                    }
                });


    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    hi.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, mpPlayer);
    hi.revalidate();




   hi.show();
```

Comment: You don't need a `revalidate()` call before `show()` the path to the file looks wrong does a file with two mp4 extensions exist in the downloads folder in your PC? This obviously won't work on the device and might fail in the media playback too. Do you get a valid input stream to that file?

Comment: Also notice that it's always better to play from file/URL than from an input stream